# Is it possible to use an SQL database while Spark is writing to it?

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc, apache-spark, amazon-rds

First of all, I am using Spark 1.5.2 on Amazon EMR and using Amazon RDS for my postgres database.

I am currently working on getting Spark to write its results to a postgres database, which I am doing by using Spark's jdbc API. While it is working correctly, what concerns me is that if I try to connect to the db using psql while Spark is running, and then try to read from the table Spark is writing to, it tells me there are no rows written yet. This persists until Spark has finished, and then suddenly all the rows appear in the db.

This worries me because the end set-up should be to regularly run the Spark script, and write more data to the db, while a website is supposed to be using that db. Does this mean that I won't be able to query the db while Spark is running?

What would you guess is the issue here? I thought it might be a matter of using a bigger instance for the db (I initially used the smallest and cheapest - db.t2.micro), but I get the same issue with a db.m4.xlarge class instance (though the time to complete the step was halved).

Comment: Time to learn the basics: [Transaction Isolation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html)

Comment: Spark is likely using one transaction for inserting all data. The problem is not that you can't read *anything* while Spark is writing, it's that when you read, no data has been committed yet.

Comment: @deceze Actually each partition is saved separately within its own transaction.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the other posters are correct. Spark is using a transaction to write to the database, so you don't see any data until the transaction is committed.

Secondly, if you really do need data to be inserted in smaller batches or as individual writes, you can always write your own JDBC code and use a map() operation, although this probably isn't a great idea (but I don't know what your use case is, so maybe there is a good reason why you would want this).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As other posters have noted, I do still need to learn the basics, but kind of in a tight spot where I have to use tech I'm really not ready to use, so I'll have to make due with asking stupid questions on stack overflow. And no, I don't need it writing in smaller batches, my concern was whether the DB is actually usable while the writing is happening, and it is. So I won't be writing my own JDBC code because most likely I'll mess it up horribly, and it's not really necessary.